# Extracting a path variable from an included URL pattern in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Been scratching my head quite a bit with this one, can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

So, the problem is that I cannot seem to extract the path variable that I want from a `urls.py` inside an app to pass it to the function that should be called when the path is visited. This URL configuration where I am trying to get it is a nested one that is included when one visits events/, here is how it looks:

Root URL configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^events/', include(event_urls))
]
```

And then the included URL conf from `event_urls`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'alarm/<alarm>', alarm)
]
```

Should be pretty straight forward I imagine, but the above does not work, like at all! If I construct the URLs in this way, requesting to the path events/alarm/on will state that path does not exist. After this, I figured it could not match the URL, but I don't understand why or how to fix it. I thought (from the docs) that the  part would match anything!

Now, I did some more investigating that proved to me that using a pattern for the  might be the right way to go. Adding the regex way of capturing a path variable made the function actually trigger! So, the URL matcher was much happier after I did this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'alarm/(?P<alarm>)', alarm)
]
```

Although, looking at `alarm` parameter in the alarm view function that gets called shows it as empty...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in adding a proper regex to match what format I expect the `<alarm>` part to arrive in. I'm honestly still quite puzzled as to why simply putting `<alarm>` does not work, so to that I welcome an explanation! Anyway, here is how it looks right now in working condition:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'alarm/(?P<alarm>\w+)', alarm)
]
```

This matches a word of any length, I could make it more fancy but that is besides the point of this question. So, matching the content of `<alarm>` was what made it work.

Comment: If you're using `url` (instead of the newer `path` that was introduced with Django 2.0), then you have to provide a regex that matches the data you want that variable to take. You can't just do `<alarm>` and expect it to capture anything - that's not a regex. That _would_ work with `path` in 2.0 where they simplified the url setup. You can use `.*` as the regex if you don't care what you match.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the part I was missing all along in the docs! This perfectly answers the question :)